# jQuery Form Input Suggestion

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm designing a web app, and need a way to pull strings out of a MySQL database and display them as drop down suggestions as the user types data in a form.

For example if the user has entered: "stac" the app should search the DB and provide suggestions like: "stack" "stackoverflow".  I'm looking for something simalar to how a lot of the tag fields here on Stack Overflow work.  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using PHP, this is quite simple.

I would use the `LIKE` keyword in SQL to find the relevant results.

Then I would parse the results into JSON, then return it to the client.

A quick example:

```
<?php
   $_q = ( isset( $_POST[ 'q' ] ) && !empty( $_POST[ 'q' ] ) ) ? $_POST[ 'q' ] : NULL;
   if( $_q === NULL ) {
      echo 'invalid querystring';
      exit;
   }

   //connect to the db....
   $set = $db->query( 'SELECT name FROM my_table WHERE name LIKE \'%' . $_q . '%\';' );

   $json = array();
   while( $result = $set->fetch_array() ) {
      $json[] = $result[ 'name' ];
   }

   echo json_encode( $json );
?>
```

JavaScript: (using jQuery)

```
function getResults( str ) {
    $.ajax({
        url:'suggest.php'.
        type:'POST',
        data: 'q=' + str,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function( json ) {
            //json is now an array, here's where you render the dropdown data.
        }
    });
}

$( '.suggest' ).keyup( function() {
   getResults( $( this ).val() );
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [jQuery autocomplete plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete). Either on page load or by invoking ajax, you will generate the list of strings that appear in the example by using your server side language,